# auto unlock iphone 5s into debug mode

Tags: ios, xcode, touch-id

There is a way to unlock automatically the iPhone5s locked with touchID when I launch an app into debug mode?

I thought that with "Authorize with this computer" was enough..

Comment: It isn't. You need a device dedicated to development without the passcode.

Comment: I imagined ... Thank you.

Comment: If you absolutely need to have it locked, put in the PIN at work in the morning and set the passcode lock time to 4 hours for iPads and 1 hour for iPhones, then if you do enough testing on it during the day you shouldn't need to put in the PIN too often